# Create a new column based on matched string in another column using grep function

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to use grep function to create a new column based on matched string (no match = 0, match =1) but not getting the expected results

```
#my data
data<- data.frame(col1 = c("name","no_match","123","0.19","rand?m","also_no_match"))

#string to match
match_txt <- "[0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]|name|name2|wh??|[0-9]|\\?"  #used "|" to match multiple strings

#create the new column using for loop
for (i in 1:nrow(data))
  {
data$col2[i] <- grep(match_txt , data$col1[i])
}

# I get the error below:
# Error in data$col2[i] <- grep(match_txt, data$col1[i],  ignore.case = TRUE) : replacement has length zero

#this is expected correct results:
expected_data <- data.frame(col1 = c("name","no_match","123","0.19","rand?m","also_no_match"),
                            col2 = c(1,0,1,1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep`/`grepl` are vectorised. We can directly use them on the column with the pattern, just wrap it in `as.integer` to convert logical values `TRUE`/`FALSE` to `1/0` respectively.

```
data$col2 <- as.integer(grepl("[0-9]\\.[0-9][0-9]|name|name2|wh??|[0-9]|\\?", data$col1))
data
#           col1 col2
#1          name    1
#2      no_match    0
#3           123    1
#4          0.19    1
#5        rand?m    1
#6 also_no_match    0
```

Comment: @Curious - you can "invert" `grepl` by negating it - `as.integer(!grepl("blahblah", data$col1))`

Comment: @Curious It can be but I think you can achieve the same with `grepl` by adding negation. `!grepl(pattern, ..)`.

Comment: @Ronak Shah- thank you that was easier than I thought, works perfect.